# Ошибка в команде MOV на FASM

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Программа должна производить некоторые манипуляции с регистрами, затем выводить "Hello World!"

Ошибка в строке

```
mov [temp3],ecx
```

если ее оставить, то fasm программу компилирует нормально, но если ее запустить, то она сразу вылетает и ничего не выводит. Если эту строку убрать, то все нормально отрабатывает. Что в ней не так?

```
format PE console
entry start

include 'include\win32a.inc'

section '.text' code executable
start:
    mov eax,[a]
    add eax,[b]
    mov [temp3],eax // Ошибка. Мне надо содержимое регистра eax записать по адресу temp3

    push hello2
    call [printf]
    pop ecx
    call [scanf]

    push 0
    call [ExitProcess]

section '.rdata' data readable
    hello2 db 'Hello world!', 10, 0
    a dd 1
    b dd 2
    temp3 dd ?

section '.idata' data readable import
    library kernel32, 'kernel32.dll', \
        msvcrt,   'msvcrt.dll'
    import kernel32, ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'
    import msvcrt, printf, 'printf', scanf, 'scanf'
```

P.S.Почти тот же самый код на 16 битах отрабатывает отлично, но на 32 не хочет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ прост: у вас секция `.rdata` объявлена "только для чтения" (`readable`, но не `writeable`). Естественно, что при попытке записи в такую секцию программа будет вылетать. Добавьте в объявление секции `writeable`, и все будет работать нормально. Должно получиться так:

```
section '.rdata' data readable writeable
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло.